# showing empty check box instead of hyphen in datatable

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have bulk select in a datatable.I have multi select check box at top of the fields.If I remove a check box for one item multi select checkbox 'tick' mark changes to 'hyphen'.I want to show empty checkbox instead of hyphen

```js
function updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table){
   var $table             = table.table().node();
   var $chkbox_all        = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]', $table);
   var $chkbox_checked    = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked', $table);
   var chkbox_select_all  = $('thead input[name="select_all"]', $table).get(0);

   // If none of the checkboxes are checked
   if($chkbox_checked.length === 0){
      chkbox_select_all.checked = false;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
      }

   // If all of the checkboxes are checked
   } else if ($chkbox_checked.length === $chkbox_all.length){
      chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
      }

   // If some of the checkboxes are checked
   } else {
      chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = true;
      }
   }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 var rows_selected = [];
 var table_home = $('#home_approval').DataTable({                    
             dom: 'ltp',
             "oLanguage": {
                  "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "<",
                    "sNext": ">"
                    }
                  }, 
      "lengthMenu": [5,10, 25],
                  "ordering": false,
      "searching": false,
      "iDisplayLength": 5
 });
 $('#home_approval tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
      var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

      // Get row data
      var data = table_home.row($row).data();

      // Get row ID
      var rowId = data[0];

      // Determine whether row ID is in the list of selected row IDs
      var index = $.inArray(rowId, rows_selected);

      // If checkbox is checked and row ID is not in list of selected row IDs
      if(this.checked && index === -1){
         rows_selected.push(rowId);

      // Otherwise, if checkbox is not checked and row ID is in list of selected row IDs
      } else if (!this.checked && index !== -1){
         rows_selected.splice(index, 1);
      }

      if(this.checked){
         $row.addClass('selected');
      } else {
         $row.removeClass('selected');
      }

      // Update state of "Select all" control
      updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table_home);

      // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
      e.stopPropagation();
   });

   // Handle click on table cells with checkboxes
   $('#home_approval').on('click', 'tbody td, thead th:first-child', function(e){
      $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');
   });

   // Handle click on "Select all" control
    $('thead input[name="select_all"]', table_home.table().container()).on('click', function(e){
      if(this.checked){
         $('#home_approval tbody input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').trigger('click');
      } else {
         $('#home_approval tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked').trigger('click');
      }

      // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
      e.stopPropagation();
   });

   // Handle table draw event
    table_home.on('draw', function(){
      // Update state of "Select all" control
      updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table_home);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

<table class="table table-bordered tablesorter reportTable dataTable no-footer" id="home_approval" role="grid">
  <thead class="thead-inverse"> 
  <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 14px;"><input name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox"><br></th><th title="Request Id" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 84px;">Request Id</th><th title="Requestor Name" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 94px;">Name</th><th title="Requestor ACE number" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 81px;">ACE number</th><th title="Department" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;">Practice / Unit</th><th title="Customer" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;">Customer</th><th title="Project" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;">Project</th><th title="Cost" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 68px;">Cost</th><th title="Currency" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 63px;">Currency</th><th title="Asset Type" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 64px;">Type</th><th title="Category" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;">Category</th><th class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" title="Sub-category" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;">Sub-category</th><th title="Quantity" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 24px;">Qty</th><th title="Status" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 96px;">Status</th></tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody>
  <tr role="row" class="odd selected">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">          
             
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="127" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0127" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0127</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="kalai.sambath">kalai.sambath</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE2917">ACE2917</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="ISV">ISV</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Test asset 3">Test asset 3</td> 
  <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="23" name="price" type="text" value="23"></td><td><select class="currency_type" data-currency="7" name="currency"><option value="">Select</option><option value="6">AED</option><option value="5">AUD</option><option value="7" selected="selected">CAD</option><option value="9">EUR</option><option value="3">GBP</option><option value="1">INR</option><option value="8">KWD</option><option value="11">PHP</option><option value="10">SAR</option><option value="12">SEK</option><option value="4">SGD</option><option value="2">USD</option></select></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
           Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0127" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even selected">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="3">          
             
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="124" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0124" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0124</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="prabakar.marimuthu">prabakar.marimuthu</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0053">ACE0053</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="New Initiatives">New Initiatives</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="New Initiatives">New Initiatives</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="No Client">No Client</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="No Client Project">No Client Project</td> 
  <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="2" name="price" type="text" value="2"></td><td><select class="currency_type" data-currency="9" name="currency"><option value="">Select</option><option value="6">AED</option><option value="5">AUD</option><option value="7">CAD</option><option value="9" selected="selected">EUR</option><option value="3">GBP</option><option value="1">INR</option><option value="8">KWD</option><option value="11">PHP</option><option value="10">SAR</option><option value="12">SEK</option><option value="4">SGD</option><option value="2">USD</option></select></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Laptop">
           Laptop
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="1">1</td>
  <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0124" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd selected">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="2">          
             
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="148" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0148" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0148</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="binu.john">binu.john</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0192">ACE0192</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Customer_610">Customer_610</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Project_1475">Project_1475</td> 
  <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="123" name="price" type="text" value="123"></td><td><select class="currency_type" data-currency="5" name="currency"><option value="">Select</option><option value="6">AED</option><option value="5" selected="selected">AUD</option><option value="7">CAD</option><option value="9">EUR</option><option value="3">GBP</option><option value="1">INR</option><option value="8">KWD</option><option value="11">PHP</option><option value="10">SAR</option><option value="12">SEK</option><option value="4">SGD</option><option value="2">USD</option></select></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Laptop">
           Laptop
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0148" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even selected">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">          
             
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="126" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0126" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0126</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="bhoo.thirumalai">bhoo.thirumalai</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0001">ACE0001</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Management">Management</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Project_1419">Project_1419</td> 
  <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="23" name="price" type="text" value="23"></td><td><select class="currency_type" data-currency="7" name="currency"><option value="">Select</option><option value="6">AED</option><option value="5">AUD</option><option value="7" selected="selected">CAD</option><option value="9">EUR</option><option value="3">GBP</option><option value="1">INR</option><option value="8">KWD</option><option value="11">PHP</option><option value="10">SAR</option><option value="12">SEK</option><option value="4">SGD</option><option value="2">USD</option></select></td>  <td title="Software">Software</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
            Software
         </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="qwe">qwe</td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0126" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd selected">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">          
             
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="123" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0123" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0123</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="bhoo.thirumalai">bhoo.thirumalai</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0001">ACE0001</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Management">Management</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems Inc">Aspire Systems Inc</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="DialdeIN">DialdeIN</td> 
  <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="34" name="price" type="text" value="34"></td><td><select class="currency_type" data-currency="3" name="currency"><option value="">Select</option><option value="6">AED</option><option value="5">AUD</option><option value="7">CAD</option><option value="9">EUR</option><option value="3" selected="selected">GBP</option><option value="1">INR</option><option value="8">KWD</option><option value="11">PHP</option><option value="10">SAR</option><option value="12">SEK</option><option value="4">SGD</option><option value="2">USD</option></select></td>  <td title="Software">Software</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
            Software
         </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="w">w</td>
  <td title="3">3</td>
  <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0123" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>  </tr>
 <tr role="row" class="odd selected">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="3">          
             
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="149" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0149" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0149</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="kaleraj.ramasamy">kaleraj.ramasamy</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0527">ACE0527</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Development">Development</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Java">Java</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="MineralTree, Inc.">MineralTree, Inc.</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Amethyst-Connector">Amethyst-Connector</td> 
  <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="657" name="price" type="text" value="657"></td><td><select class="currency_type" data-currency="9" name="currency"><option value="">Select</option><option value="6">AED</option><option value="5">AUD</option><option value="7">CAD</option><option value="9" selected="selected">EUR</option><option value="3">GBP</option><option value="1">INR</option><option value="8">KWD</option><option value="11">PHP</option><option value="10">SAR</option><option value="12">SEK</option><option value="4">SGD</option><option value="2">USD</option></select></td>  <td title="Software">Software</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
            Software
         </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="45">45</td>
  <td title="6">6</td>
  <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0149" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0145" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0145</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="bhoo.thirumalai">bhoo.thirumalai</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0001">ACE0001</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Management">Management</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems Inc">Aspire Systems Inc</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="DialdeIN">DialdeIN</td> 
  <td class="" title="12">12</td><td title="EUR">EUR</td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
           Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td title="Waiting for NSA Approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for NSA Approval</td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0130" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0130</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="ramesh.chandran">ramesh.chandran</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE2347">ACE2347</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="BFS">BFS</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Project_1418">Project_1418</td> 
  <td class="" title="2123">2123</td><td title="AED">AED</td>  <td title="Software">Software</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
            Software
         </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="w">w</td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td title="Waiting for NSA Approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for NSA Approval</td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0107" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0107</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="bavithra.ravichandra">bavithra.ravichandra</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE3835">ACE3835</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Development">Development</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Retail Testing">Retail Testing</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="sdfasdfr2342">sdfasdfr2342</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Project_328">Project_328</td> 
  <td class="" title="2">2</td><td title="EUR">EUR</td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
           Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="23">23</td>
  <td title="Waiting for Super practice owner approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for super.prac.owner approval</td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0090" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0090</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="arunraj.anandan">arunraj.anandan</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE2092">ACE2092</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Testing(SL)">Testing(SL)</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Retail Testing">Retail Testing</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="World of Jeans &amp; Tops, Inc dba Tillys">World of Jeans &amp; Tops, Inc dba Tillys</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Project_974">Project_974</td> 
  <td class="" title="123">123</td><td title="CAD">CAD</td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Laptop">
           Laptop
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td title="Waiting for Super practice owner approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for super.prac.owner approval</td>  </tr>   
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

How to change remove hyphen for multicheckbox in datatable

Comment: Kindly mark my answer as solved if it helped you I'll appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your `indeterminate`. The hyphen is just the browser's way to "half check" the box. Why are you using it if you don't want its style applied?

You'd need to do the following to remove this effect:

```js
function updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table) {
  var $table = table.table().node();
  var $chkbox_all = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]', $table);
  var $chkbox_checked = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked', $table);
  var chkbox_select_all = $('thead input[name="select_all"]', $table).get(0);

  // If none of the checkboxes are checked
  if ($chkbox_checked.length === 0) {
    chkbox_select_all.checked = false;

    // If all of the checkboxes are checked
  } else if ($chkbox_checked.length === $chkbox_all.length) {
    chkbox_select_all.checked = true;

    // If some of the checkboxes are checked
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rows_selected = [];
  var table_home = $('#home_approval').DataTable({
    dom: 'ltp',
    "oLanguage": {
      "oPaginate": {
        "sPrevious": "<",
        "sNext": ">"
      }
    },
    "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25],
    "ordering": false,
    "searching": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 5
  });
  $('#home_approval tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

    // Get row data
    var data = table_home.row($row).data();

    // Get row ID
    var rowId = data[0];

    // Determine whether row ID is in the list of selected row IDs
    var index = $.inArray(rowId, rows_selected);

    // If checkbox is checked and row ID is not in list of selected row IDs
    if (this.checked && index === -1) {
      rows_selected.push(rowId);

      // Otherwise, if checkbox is not checked and row ID is in list of selected row IDs
    } else if (!this.checked && index !== -1) {
      rows_selected.splice(index, 1);
    }

    if (this.checked) {
      $row.addClass('selected');
    } else {
      $row.removeClass('selected');
    }

    // Update state of "Select all" control
    updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table_home);

    // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  // Handle click on table cells with checkboxes
  $('#home_approval').on('click', 'tbody td, thead th:first-child', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');
  });

  // Handle click on "Select all" control
  $('thead input[name="select_all"]', table_home.table().container()).on('click', function(e) {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#home_approval tbody input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').trigger('click');
    } else {
      $('#home_approval tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked').trigger('click');
    }

    // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  // Handle table draw event
  table_home.on('draw', function() {
    // Update state of "Select all" control
    updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table_home);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<table class="table table-bordered tablesorter reportTable dataTable no-footer" id="home_approval" role="grid">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 14px;"><input name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox"><br></th>
      <th title="Request Id" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 84px;">Request Id</th>
      <th title="Requestor Name" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 94px;">Name</th>
      <th title="Requestor ACE number" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 81px;">ACE number</th>
      <th title="Department" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;">Practice / Unit</th>
      <th title="Customer" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;">Customer</th>
      <th title="Project" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;">Project</th>
      <th title="Cost" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 68px;">Cost</th>
      <th title="Currency" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 63px;">Currency</th>
      <th title="Asset Type" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 64px;">Type</th>
      <th title="Category" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;">Category</th>
      <th class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" title="Sub-category" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 95px;">Sub-category</th>
      <th title="Quantity" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 24px;">Qty</th>
      <th title="Status" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 96px;">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd selected">
      <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">

      <td><input id="select_update" data-id="127" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0127" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0127</a></td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="kalai.sambath">kalai.sambath</td>
      <td class="" title="ACE2917">ACE2917</td>
      <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="ISV">ISV</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Test asset 3">Test asset 3</td>
      <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="23" name="price" type="text" value="23"></td>
      <td>
        <select class="currency_type" data-currency="7" name="currency">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="6">AED</option>
          <option value="5">AUD</option>
          <option value="7" selected="selected">CAD</option>
          <option value="9">EUR</option>
          <option value="3">GBP</option>
          <option value="1">INR</option>
          <option value="8">KWD</option>
          <option value="11">PHP</option>
          <option value="10">SAR</option>
          <option value="12">SEK</option>
          <option value="4">SGD</option>
          <option value="2">USD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
        Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
      <td title="2">2</td>
      <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0127" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even selected">
      <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="3">

      <td><input id="select_update" data-id="124" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0124" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0124</a></td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="prabakar.marimuthu">prabakar.marimuthu</td>
      <td class="" title="ACE0053">ACE0053</td>
      <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="New Initiatives">New Initiatives</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="New Initiatives">New Initiatives</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="No Client">No Client</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="No Client Project">No Client Project</td>
      <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="2" name="price" type="text" value="2"></td>
      <td>
        <select class="currency_type" data-currency="9" name="currency">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="6">AED</option>
          <option value="5">AUD</option>
          <option value="7">CAD</option>
          <option value="9" selected="selected">EUR</option>
          <option value="3">GBP</option>
          <option value="1">INR</option>
          <option value="8">KWD</option>
          <option value="11">PHP</option>
          <option value="10">SAR</option>
          <option value="12">SEK</option>
          <option value="4">SGD</option>
          <option value="2">USD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Laptop">
        Laptop
      </td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
      <td title="1">1</td>
      <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0124" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd selected">
      <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="2">

      <td><input id="select_update" data-id="148" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0148" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0148</a></td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="binu.john">binu.john</td>
      <td class="" title="ACE0192">ACE0192</td>
      <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Customer_610">Customer_610</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Project_1475">Project_1475</td>
      <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="123" name="price" type="text" value="123"></td>
      <td>
        <select class="currency_type" data-currency="5" name="currency">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="6">AED</option>
          <option value="5" selected="selected">AUD</option>
          <option value="7">CAD</option>
          <option value="9">EUR</option>
          <option value="3">GBP</option>
          <option value="1">INR</option>
          <option value="8">KWD</option>
          <option value="11">PHP</option>
          <option value="10">SAR</option>
          <option value="12">SEK</option>
          <option value="4">SGD</option>
          <option value="2">USD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Laptop">
        Laptop
      </td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
      <td title="2">2</td>
      <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0148" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even selected">
      <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">

      <td><input id="select_update" data-id="126" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0126" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0126</a></td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="bhoo.thirumalai">bhoo.thirumalai</td>
      <td class="" title="ACE0001">ACE0001</td>
      <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Management">Management</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Project_1419">Project_1419</td>
      <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="23" name="price" type="text" value="23"></td>
      <td>
        <select class="currency_type" data-currency="7" name="currency">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="6">AED</option>
          <option value="5">AUD</option>
          <option value="7" selected="selected">CAD</option>
          <option value="9">EUR</option>
          <option value="3">GBP</option>
          <option value="1">INR</option>
          <option value="8">KWD</option>
          <option value="11">PHP</option>
          <option value="10">SAR</option>
          <option value="12">SEK</option>
          <option value="4">SGD</option>
          <option value="2">USD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td title="Software">Software</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
        Software
      </td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="qwe">qwe</td>
      <td title="2">2</td>
      <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0126" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd selected">
      <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">

      <td><input id="select_update" data-id="123" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0123" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0123</a></td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="bhoo.thirumalai">bhoo.thirumalai</td>
      <td class="" title="ACE0001">ACE0001</td>
      <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Management">Management</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems Inc">Aspire Systems Inc</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="DialdeIN">DialdeIN</td>
      <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="34" name="price" type="text" value="34"></td>
      <td>
        <select class="currency_type" data-currency="3" name="currency">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="6">AED</option>
          <option value="5">AUD</option>
          <option value="7">CAD</option>
          <option value="9">EUR</option>
          <option value="3" selected="selected">GBP</option>
          <option value="1">INR</option>
          <option value="8">KWD</option>
          <option value="11">PHP</option>
          <option value="10">SAR</option>
          <option value="12">SEK</option>
          <option value="4">SGD</option>
          <option value="2">USD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td title="Software">Software</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
        Software
      </td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="w">w</td>
      <td title="3">3</td>
      <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0123" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd selected">
      <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="3">

      <td><input id="select_update" data-id="149" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0149" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0149</a></td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="kaleraj.ramasamy">kaleraj.ramasamy</td>
      <td class="" title="ACE0527">ACE0527</td>
      <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Development">Development</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Java">Java</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="MineralTree, Inc.">MineralTree, Inc.</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Amethyst-Connector">Amethyst-Connector</td>
      <td><input id="price" class="price_review used_asset1" maxlength="8" placeholder="Amt" data-price="657" name="price" type="text" value="657"></td>
      <td>
        <select class="currency_type" data-currency="9" name="currency">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="6">AED</option>
          <option value="5">AUD</option>
          <option value="7">CAD</option>
          <option value="9" selected="selected">EUR</option>
          <option value="3">GBP</option>
          <option value="1">INR</option>
          <option value="8">KWD</option>
          <option value="11">PHP</option>
          <option value="10">SAR</option>
          <option value="12">SEK</option>
          <option value="4">SGD</option>
          <option value="2">USD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td title="Software">Software</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
        Software
      </td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="45">45</td>
      <td title="6">6</td>
      <td title="Waiting for Review" class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0149" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for Review</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">
      <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0145" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0145</a></td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="bhoo.thirumalai">bhoo.thirumalai</td>
      <td class="" title="ACE0001">ACE0001</td>
      <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Management">Management</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems Inc">Aspire Systems Inc</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="DialdeIN">DialdeIN</td>
      <td class="" title="12">12</td>
      <td title="EUR">EUR</td>
      <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
        Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
      <td title="2">2</td>
      <td title="Waiting for NSA Approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for NSA Approval</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">
      <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0130" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0130</a></td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="ramesh.chandran">ramesh.chandran</td>
      <td class="" title="ACE2347">ACE2347</td>
      <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="BFS">BFS</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Project_1418">Project_1418</td>
      <td class="" title="2123">2123</td>
      <td title="AED">AED</td>
      <td title="Software">Software</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
        Software
      </td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="w">w</td>
      <td title="2">2</td>
      <td title="Waiting for NSA Approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for NSA Approval</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">
      <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0107" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0107</a></td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="bavithra.ravichandra">bavithra.ravichandra</td>
      <td class="" title="ACE3835">ACE3835</td>
      <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Development">Development</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Retail Testing">Retail Testing</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="sdfasdfr2342">sdfasdfr2342</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Project_328">Project_328</td>
      <td class="" title="2">2</td>
      <td title="EUR">EUR</td>
      <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
        Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
      <td title="23">23</td>
      <td title="Waiting for Super practice owner approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for super.prac.owner approval</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">
      <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0090" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0090</a></td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="arunraj.anandan">arunraj.anandan</td>
      <td class="" title="ACE2092">ACE2092</td>
      <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Testing(SL)">Testing(SL)</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Retail Testing">Retail Testing</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="World of Jeans &amp; Tops, Inc dba Tillys">World of Jeans &amp; Tops, Inc dba Tillys</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Project_974">Project_974</td>
      <td class="" title="123">123</td>
      <td title="CAD">CAD</td>
      <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Laptop">
        Laptop
      </td>
      <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
      <td title="2">2</td>
      <td title="Waiting for Super practice owner approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for super.prac.owner approval</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't remove tick intermediate still it showing tick mark in select all

Comment: i'm using chrome